# On click of button, increment number by 1

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reactjs, express

Trying to make the number increment by 1 on click event,
wondering what's the right approach to this?

In my render():

```
{this.state.posts.map((post, i) =>
     <div key={post._id}>

         <span>Votes: {post.votes}</span>


         <a href="" onClick={() => this.votePost(post._id, i)}>
             Click Me
         </a>
     </div>
 )}
```

initial state:

```
state = {
    posts: [],
};
```

on click function:

```
votePost = async id => {
    await axios.put(`/posts/${id}`);

    this.setState({

    })
};
```

Backend:

```
router.put('posts/:post_id', async (req, res, next) => {
try {
    const { post_id } = req.params;
    const { votes } = req.body;

    const doc = await Post.findByIdAndUpdate(post_id, { votes });
    res.status(200).send(doc);
} catch (e) {
    next(e);
}
});
```

Comment: where are you getting newPostData form? If you are getting it from server then its fine but you need to update that particular post only, No need to reset entire posts.

Comment: One more thing you can do is you can set the incremented vote on client side first then make a server call, but then you need to check if there is an error from server then you need to decrement it by 1 again on client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change a value for a specific entry of a state array, you need to keep track of the index in your render loop :

```
{this.state.posts.map((post, i) =>
     <div key={post._id}>

         <span>Votes: {post.votes}</span>


         <a href="" onClick={() => this.votePost(post._id, i)}>
             Click Me
         </a>
     </div>
 )}
```

So you can change the value for the right post in your votePost function

```
votePost = async (id, index) => {

    await axios.put(`/posts/${id}/upvote` /*or downvote*/);

        ....

    });

    // Update your state like this:
    this.setState(({posts})=>{
       posts[index] = newPostData;
       return posts
    });
}
```

**Edit:**

For the backend, you can eventually create two endpoints `/upvote` and `/downvote`:

```
const vote = (req, res, next)=>{
    try {
       const { post_id } = req.params;
       const doc = await Post.findByIdAndUpdate(post_id, ({ votes })=>({votes: req.voteup ? votes + 1 : votes - 1});
       res.status(200).send(doc);
   } catch (e) {
    next(e);
   }
}

router.put('posts/:post_id/upvote', async (req, res, next) => {
    req.voteup = true;
    vote(req, res, next);
});

router.put('posts/:post_id/downvote', async (req, res, next) => {
    req.voteup = false;
    vote(req, res, next);
});
```

Comment: Here is a very basic sandbox exemple : https://codesandbox.io/s/m710lq4vpx

Comment: It works great on front end, but I wonder how you would save that in the backend? or should we do the whole incrementing logic in the backend? I've updated my post to show the backend

Comment: I made an edit to propose something for the backend, but didn't have much time tonight. i'll improve if necessary...

Answer (score 0):

To increment a number by 1 on click you can use the following code.

```js
constructor() {
    this.state = {
        count: 0
    }
}


handleOnCLick = () => {
  this.setState((prevState) => (count: prevState.count + 1))
}

<button onClick={this.handleOnCLick}/>
```

Comment: In this case you need to decrement the vote in case there is an error form server.